# After a successful transaction in Paypal Sandbox, how can i update my site with values?

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox, paypal-ipn

**can i ask if what code should i put in my .php in order for my site to update values after a successful purchase using paypal sandbox? i'm already done with making transactions in paypal sandbox.. the problem is, how can it reflect to my site?**

example a simple game that you should purchase coins in order to buy items:

**MySite (has a current coins of 0) > after i choose to purchase 5 coins for $3 > make successful payment > then going back to my site it should have the value of 5 coins now..**

Comment: Look into [Paypal's Instant Payment Notification](https://www.paypal.com/ipn).

Answer (score 0):

Store the values you're talking about in some form of database, then make your php script update them after each successful payment (afaik, payment systems usually allow to specify some kind of a callback function, which will be execute when transaction is complete). You'd also add a logic for fetching these values from the DB when the start page is shown.

Comment: thank you for the reply sir.. but the thing i dont get is.. after the successful transaction.. and then when i go back to my site.. how can the value be updated? sorry sir im just a newbie programmer.. and im confused w/ paypal sandbox > site thingy..